# Question about making a repository structure

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I'm currently starting a new job at the university and I want to have my file 'architecture' on my laptop nicely structured. In my student times (half a year ago) I (mis)used github to have a repository with all my writings (TeX), code (Matlab) and research (in terms of pdf papers) in one big repository (therefore misused). I mostly used it as a online backup and version control.

Now I want to have it a bit more structured, such that I can share for example a piece of the writing (e.g. when writing a joint paper). But I want to avoid to have a zillion repositories. So my question is, can I have a some sort of master repository which contains a structure and some personal files, code, documents and some separate 'sub'-repos that contain the information I want to share. So, if you consider the following screenshot, the blue would be the main repos called 'work' and the other colors would be subrepositories of 'work', but can be shared separately. So if I clone 'work', I get all the colors, but if I clone 'Joint Paper 1', I only see the content of this folder.

[image: Examplified]

It would also be nice to do a single commit for the main and subrepositories (if wanted)

I tried to implement this in Gitlab using groups, but that didn't work out as I wanted, as the structure could not be cloned to my windows explorer file manager...

Is the thing I want possible with Git based tools? And if so, how?

Comment: Sounds like "a zillion repositories" is a much better model. You can group them with tags on Github.

Comment: What you are describing sounds a lot like git submodule, but be cautious before you decide to use it. It has some gotchas especially if you share your work with people that are not used to work with submodules.